# Save a list of tuple to csv file in python

Tags: python, list, csv, tuples

I have a list of tuple which looks like this:

```
data = [(1633098324445950024, 139.55, 15, [14, 37, 41]),
        (1633098324445958000, 139.55, 100, [14, 41]),
        (1633098324445958498, 139.55, 60, [14, 37, 41]),
        (1633098324446013523, 139.55, 52, [14, 37, 41]),
        (1633098324472392943, 139.555, 100),
        (1633098324478972256, 139.555, 100)]
```

I am trying to save it in a `csv` file with:

```
def save_csv(data, path, filename):
    with open(os.path.join(path, str(filename) + '_data.csv'), "w") as outfile:
        outfile.write("\n".join(f"{r[0]},{r[1]},{r[2]},{r[3]}" for r in data))

save_csv(data, path, filename)
```

I am getting the `IndexError`:

```
    outfile.write("\n".join(f"{r[0]},{r[1]},{r[2]},{r[3]}" for r in data))

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I would like the result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: The last two rows only have 3 elements, so there's no `r[3]`

Comment: As an aside, the resulting file is not a CSV - the final column has unescaped comma separators in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a variable number of columns - `r[3]` won't always exist. This is a great use case for pandas which will add defaults as needed. I bit more subtle, but pandas will also quote the final column so that that a later reader will know to ignore its embedded commas.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [(1633098324445950024, 139.55, 15, [14, 37, 41]),
        (1633098324445958000, 139.55, 100, [14, 41]),
        (1633098324445958498, 139.55, 60, [14, 37, 41]),
        (1633098324446013523, 139.55, 52, [14, 37, 41]),
        (1633098324472392943, 139.555, 100),
        (1633098324478972256, 139.555, 100)]

pd.DataFrame(data).to_csv("test.csv")
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import csv

data = [(1633098324445950024, 139.55, 15, [14, 37, 41]),
        (1633098324445958000, 139.55, 100, [14, 41]),
        (1633098324445958498, 139.55, 60, [14, 37, 41]),
        (1633098324446013523, 139.55, 52, [14, 37, 41]),
        (1633098324472392943, 139.555, 100),
        (1633098324478972256, 139.555, 100)]

with open("csv.csv", "w") as f:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f)
    for mytuple in data:
        csv_writer.writerow(mytuple)
```

Comment: This is the right solution, as the csv module will correctly quote the list so that the commas are not treated as field delimiters.